# How to skip running useEffect on first run is Strict mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that I use when I need to skip running of the `useEffect` function on a first call. This works like a charm in non [Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

`hooks/useEffectSkipFirst.js`

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default (fn, deps) => {
  const isFirstRun = useRef(true);

  const execFunc = useCallback(fn, deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;
      return;
    }
    execFunc();
  }, [execFunc])
};
```

Usage:

```
import useEffectSkipFirst from 'hooks/useEffectSkipFirst';

useEffectSkipFirst(() => {
  // fetch new user by ID
}, [selectedUser.id])
```

Obviously, this hook works completely differently in Strict mode where it will execute a function on the first call because the `useEffect` hook will be called twice. The reason why it will be called twice is the fact that its dependency is a variable returned from `useState` (or react-redux's `useSelector`) which gets called twice in Strict mode. Therefore it makes an API call on the first run while it shouldn't until the user changes.

The only way I can fix this is by listening to `NODE_ENV` variable, and in case of development, I would block execution of the function until 3rd call while blocking until 2nd call in case of other envs. Unfortunately, that sounds like a poor solution to me.

Is there a better way to write a custom hook that works in both modes? Bear in mind that it is important to write a hook that doesn't throw any `eslint-plugin-react-hook` warnings.

EDIT: Epic facepalm on my end. The reason why everything works for me in non Strict mode and doesn't in Strict is that all my routes are rendered through `Private.js` component which checks whether I already have a user in store (logged in) or not. In case I don't have a user it will make an API call. Because I'm doing the check within render function (wrong to have side effects in that check) and render is called twice in Strict mode I'm actually making 2 API calls (bug). That also means my Redux store gets updated twice and thus triggers my useEffect twice which has that variable as a dependency. I've been looking for the bug in the wrong place the whole time. I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Why would the effect run twice upon being mounted? Effects runs the same way regardless of being rendered in a react `StrictMode` or not. [Try it out in a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-skip-running-useeffect-on-first-run-is-strict-mode-39f75?file=/src/App.js) I think you are conflating the react framework invoking the render function twice during the render phase vs the effect running only once during the commit phase (after the UI is rendered). Perhaps you've some other issue happening?

Comment: Strict mode is revealing that this concept might be flawed. What does "first render" actually mean to you? Having a hook run "exactly once" is a concept that would be supported, but what about "first render", when thought about in strict mode, is it that your hook is trying to accomplish?

Comment: *"Therefore it makes an API call on the first run while it shouldn't until the user changes"*. Just add another condition to your `if` statement then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need my answer but I could come across with this workaround:

```js
setTimeout(() => (isFirstRender.current = false), 1000);
```

By setting the ref to false only after 1 second of timeout, React can run its useEffect as often as it can, the if check will fail on the first render. With that I can easily start my countdown timer only onClick so if my dependency changes.